# Preserving Object References with newtonsoft Json with objects own Id

Tags: json, json.net

I am studying [Preserving Object References](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm) with newtonsoft Json.
When I run the following code,

```
class Person
{
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static int m_Counter = 20;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person p1 = new Person
        {
            Id = m_Counter++,
            BirthDate = new DateTime(1980, 12, 23, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
            LastModified = new DateTime(2009, 2, 20, 12, 59, 21, DateTimeKind.Utc),
            Name = "James"
        };

        Person p2 = new Person
        {
            Id = m_Counter++,
            BirthDate = new DateTime(1980, 12, 23, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
            LastModified = new DateTime(2009, 2, 20, 12, 59, 21, DateTimeKind.Utc),
            Name = "James"
        };

        List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
        people.Add(p1);
        people.Add(p1); // Adding the same person twice.

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(people, Formatting.Indented
            , new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                PreserveReferencesHandling
                    = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
            }
            );
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I get the following JSON

```
[
  {
    "$id": "1",
    "BirthDate": "1980-12-23T00:00:00Z",
    "LastModified": "2009-02-20T12:59:21Z",
    "Name": "James",
    "Id": 20
  },
  {
    "$ref": "1"
  }
]
```

Here I see that Newtonsoft is creating its own id for each object.
So I am wondering if there is any way to instruct Newtonsoft to use the Id of the object itself(20 here in this case) instead of creating its own("$id": "1")

Comment: It is using ID 20 for both.  the first one clearly shows that.  When you deserialize both object will be 20.  The "$Id" is a simply how it implements `PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects`

Comment: I don't think you can change names of the `"$ref"` and `"$id"` properties.  Those are built into Json.NET.  It's possible you could create your own [`IReferenceResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IReferenceResolver.htm) and change the *value of `$id`* to something like `"Person_1"` for your `Person` class.  Would that be of use?